# Group rows based on value aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query whose purpose is to group multiple sequential rows for future processing. The rules for such grouping are:

- Each row has a segment identifier and a corresponding weight.
- As many contiguous segments as possible must be grouped together, provided that their total weight does not exceed the specified threshold.
- If a segment has weight exceeding the specified threshold, the resulting group will only represent that segment.

Here is an example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpIncoming;

CREATE TABLE #tmpIncoming
(
  [Segment] int NOT NULL,
  [Weight]  int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmpIncoming VALUES
( 1,  25),
( 2,  45),
( 3,  20),
( 4,  30),
( 5,  50),
( 6,  21),
( 7, 110);

DECLARE @nMaxChunkSize int = 100;

-- BEGIN: suboptimal
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpResult;

CREATE TABLE #tmpResult
(
    [MinSegment] int NOT NULL,
    [MaxSegment] int NOT NULL,
    [Weight]   int NOT NULL
);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
SELECT
    [Segment],
    [Weight]
FROM
    #tmpIncoming
ORDER BY
    [Segment];

OPEN cur;

DECLARE @nMinSegment int = 0, @nMaxSegment int = 0;
DECLARE @nWeightSoFar int = 0;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nSegment int, @nWeight int;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @nSegment, @nWeight;

    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
        BREAK;

    IF (@nWeightSoFar + @nWeight > @nMaxChunkSize)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tmpResult ([MinSegment], [MaxSegment], [Weight])
        VALUES (@nMinSegment, @nMaxSegment, @nWeightSoFar);

        SET @nMinSegment = @nSegment;
        SET @nMaxSegment = @nSegment;
        SET @nWeightSoFar = @nWeight;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@nMinSegment = 0)
            SET @nMinSegment = @nSegment;
        SET @nMaxSegment = @nSegment;
        SET @nWeightSoFar = @nWeightSoFar + @nWeight;
    END;
END;

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

IF (@nWeightSoFar > 0)
    INSERT INTO #tmpResult ([MinSegment], [MaxSegment], [Weight])
    VALUES (@nMinSegment, @nMaxSegment, @nWeightSoFar);

SELECT * FROM #tmpResult;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpResult;
-- END: suboptimal

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpIncoming;
```

I was only able to think of a suboptimal implementation which uses a cursor variable. Can anyone recommend a better approach, preferably with only one SELECT and maybe some CTE?

Comment: Take a look at this (is in Python, but could help you) --> [Pandas - Group Rows based on a column and replace NaN with non-null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167900/pandas-group-rows-based-on-a-column-and-replace-nan-with-non-null-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to cycle through the weights in order and, as soon as you exceed your chunk size, reset.

```
DECLARE @nMaxChunkSize int = 100;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Segment, 
         Weight, 
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Segment)
    FROM #tmpIncoming
),
cte AS 
(
  SELECT Segment, Weight, rn, total = Weight, flip = 0 
  FROM x 
  WHERE rn = 1
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT x.Segment, x.Weight, x.rn, total = CASE 
    WHEN x.Weight + cte.Total > @nMaxChunkSize 
    THEN x.Weight ELSE x.Weight + cte.Total END,
    flip = flip + CASE 
    WHEN x.Weight + cte.Total > @nMaxChunkSize 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM x JOIN cte  
  ON x.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
SELECT MinSegment = MIN(Segment), 
       MaxSegment = MAX(Segment),
       Weight     = MAX(total)
FROM cte
GROUP BY flip
ORDER BY MinSegment
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Results:

| MinSegment | MaxSegment | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 90 |
| 4 | 5 | 80 |
| 6 | 6 | 21 |
| 7 | 7 | 110 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6559cf101e2c57aa7313e1c9305eba3d)

Another way that yields the same results but may be a little easier to break apart / follow (though arguably the code quickly becomes as verbose as the original):

```
DECLARE @nMaxChunkSize int = 100;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Segment, 
         Weight, 
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Segment)
    FROM #tmpIncoming
),
cte AS 
(
  SELECT Segment, Weight, rn, Total = Weight
  FROM x 
  WHERE rn = 1
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT x.Segment, x.Weight, x.rn, Total = CASE 
    WHEN x.Weight + cte.Total > @nMaxChunkSize 
    THEN x.Weight ELSE x.Weight + cte.Total END
  FROM x JOIN cte ON x.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
SELECT MinSegment = MIN(Segment), 
       MaxSegment = MAX(Segment),
       Weight     = MAX(Total)
FROM 
(
  SELECT Segment, Total, 
    NewGroup = SUM(CASE WHEN Weight = Total THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (ORDER BY Segment ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) FROM cte
) AS y
GROUP BY NewGroup
ORDER BY MinSegment
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

- That fiddle is here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4dd5998ddb7ee432842e63ddb4a231b)

Comment: Hi @Aaron Bertrand! Thanks for the suggestion. Works great on the demo data. However, it crashes on my production case where the incoming data contains about 2000 rows representing segments:
```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand perfectly good point — my mistake. Now everything works! You are phenomenal! Just out of curiosity: since my cursor-based solution seems to run faster in the production case, which solution would you pick yourself?

Comment: @Kerido I would probably use the one that runs faster. Even if it were a little slower, if it's much easier to understand, maintain, adjust for future logic changes, etc. There is nothing really wrong with a cursor if it gets the job done, though knowing how to convert it to set-based logic is a valuable skill, because at some scale it may stop getting the job done. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the calculations, I do not think this can be done with windowed functions.
I would be inclined to use a .NET DataReader either on the application server or using the CLR.
If you really want to use SQL you could try the Quirky Update:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten

but be aware it is non-relational and could be broken by a Microsoft patch.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
    Segment int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Weight] int NOT NULL
    ,MinSegment int NULL
    ,WeightSoFar int NULL
);
INSERT INTO #t (Segment, [Weight])
SELECT Segment, [Weight]
FROM #tmpIncoming;

DECLARE @nMaxChunkSize int = 100
    ,@WeightSoFar int = 0
    ,@Break int = 0
    ,@MinSegment int = 1
    ,@Check int
    ,@Anchor int;

UPDATE #t
SET @Break =
        CASE
            WHEN [Weight] + @WeightSoFar > @nMaxChunkSize
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ,@WeightSoFar =
        CASE
            WHEN @Break = 1
            THEN [Weight]
            ELSE [Weight] + @WeightSoFar
        END
    ,@MinSegment =
        CASE
            WHEN @Break = 1
            THEN Segment
            ELSE @MinSegment
        END
    ,WeightSoFar = @WeightSoFar
    ,MinSegment = @MinSegment
    -- Double check running in segment order
    ,@check = CASE WHEN Segment > ISNULL(@Anchor, -1) THEN 1 ELSE 1/0 END
    ,@Anchor = Segment
FROM #t WITH (TABLOCKX)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT MinSegment
    ,MAX(Segment) AS MaxSegment
    ,MAX(WeightSoFar) AS [Weight]
FROM #t
GROUP BY MinSegment;

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
```

Comment: nice all in one - can you explain the   @check = ... **ELSE 1/0** ?

Comment: The check means that if for some reason the update does not occur in the order of the clustered index (segment) then divide by zero will be thrown. ie You know that you have to look at a different solution. That being said the quirky update has always worked in SQL Server if all the rules are followed. It still works in SQL2019 but as it is undocumented by Microsoft, and non-relational, it might not with SQL2022.