# SQL Server Difference of Aggregate Window

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch some data from an SQL Server table by creating windows of 15 mins from the start time and find the difference between the MAX and MIN of a certain column (value) in these windows.

The SQL Table stores some telemetry data captured every minute.

Are there any T-SQL functionalities that I can utilize to get such output without running a loop (Windowed Aggregation sort, etc.)?

I could implement this using a loop, but this is very slow as it would take data from every window and add it to a temp table. Below is a dumbed-down snippet of the code:

```
WHILE(@startTime <@endTimeInput)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #energyDataTable
    SELECT  MIN(timeStamp) as startTime, MAX(timeStamp) as endTime, ROUND(MAX (value) - MIN (value),2) as value
    FROM PLANT1.DATA_TABLE as ts
    WHERE ts.unixTimestamp>=@startTime and ts.unixTimestamp<= @endTime
    GROUP BY ts.logicalId
    
    --Increment startTime and endTime to goto next window
    SET @startTime = @endTime;
    SET @endTime = @startTime + 15 * 60000; --converting 15 mins to millisecs
END
```

| Timestamp | value | unixTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2021-11-08 00:00:09.000** | **1527.6** | 1636329609000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:01:09.000 | 1528.1 | 1636329669000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:02:09.000 | 1528.6 | 1636329729000 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 2021-11-08 00:13:09.000 | 1534.5 | 1636330389000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:14:09.000** | **1535.3** | 1636330479000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:15:09.000** | **1535.5** | 1636330509000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:16:09.000 | 1536.0 | 1636330569000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:17:09.000 | 1528.6 | 1636330629000 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 2021-11-08 00:28:09.000 | 1542.5 | 1636331289000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:29:09.000** | **1543.3** | 1636331379000 |

Needs to be transformed to (I don't necessarily need end_time: Added for better understanding):

| start_time | end_time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-08 00:00:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:14:39.000 | 7.7 |
| 2021-11-08 00:15:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:29:39.000 | 7.8 |

Comment: You start by saying 15min windows? But your expected results show two ranges of 4mins?  (Should the windows always base themselves from midnight? Or from the time in the first record? Are there Guaranteed to be no gaps, duplicates, or other unusual records?) *(You probably just need RANGE BETWEEN or ROWS BETWEEN in your windowed functions. But, you haven't shown the SQL you tried, so that's just guessing.)*

Comment: Right, did you mean 5 minutes but say 15? Or do you mean you want to take 15 minutes of data and slice it into 5-minute intervals? And can you clarify what `01:01:05` means? Can you please try to make sure the sample data matches the word problem?

Comment: Your results don't make much sense, 01:01:05 falls within the range of the first aggregate?

Comment: Presumably your desired results should be `01:06:00 - 01:10:00`, but thats a window of 5 minutes not 15

Comment: Also, `without running a loop (Want to avoid at this as it would be a non-optimal solution).` - how do you know? Generally, yes, "loops are bad" but [sometimes they are worth trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899947/group-rows-based-on-value-aggregation/69900474#comment123567428_69900474) (and can also be useful to validate set-based results).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have tried similar problem statements using loops. There is a considerable time difference. I have a service that loops over 1000's rows of data every one hour. I recently updated it to make it a single query and saw a HUGE time difference. That is why I came to the inference.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @Stu and Aaron. I had to make the original interval as 15 mins but as the example table would've been long, I made it 5 mins for simplicity but forgot to update the text. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: But you haven't built a set-based query that gets the right results, right? That's why you're here? So how do you know there _is_ a set-based solution that is both faster than a loop _and_ gets the right results? I'm not saying that won't be the case, but don't jump to that conclusion by taking one experience and applying it to all others. Again, sometimes a loop is the best way, and sometimes it's slower by such a negligible amount that the difficulty in developing, maintaining, and understanding the solution isn't worth it.

Comment: Back to the problem, there is still some confusion here and some clarity lacking. Your windows are `01:01:00 - 01:05:00` and `01:01:05 - 01:09:00`, this makes no sense as they overlap. Next, where does `01:00:00` fall? Seems inconsistent if it's in the window *prior* to `01:01` but then `01:10` is in the window _after_ `01:09`? Do you have a row for every single minute window? And is there never any second associated? Build a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with real sample data, please. Then length is much less of an issue and nothing has to get dumbed down.

Comment: (Also a loop-based solution that you come up with that does get the answer you need, while not the best ultimate solution, might better help us in the meantime better understand the problem you're solving, and avoid assumptions about the data you can make that you might not know we need to make - or hassle you to clarify.)

Comment: What you said does make sense. I will implement that and send it to you tomorrow. Thanks @AaronBertrand

Comment: Other information that will be useful - are you always trying to get summary information for data within a single day (or within a max range of n minutes within that day, or always the whole day, or something else)? Or will your range sometimes span days? In which case shouldn't date be part of the output? And if you have a 5 minute row with no data, do you want a row with 0, or a row with null, or no row, or ...?

Comment: Questions have been updated according to the new feedback @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 2):

**update**

the solution is to get first and last row from 15 mins sections

it can be done like this:

```
create table #t
(
     ts datetime2
    ,val dec(9,2)
)

insert into #t
values
 ('2021-11-08 00:00:09.000', 1527.6)
,('2021-11-08 00:01:09.000', 1528.1)
,('2021-11-08 00:02:09.000', 1528.6)
,('2021-11-08 00:13:09.000', 1534.5)
,('2021-11-08 00:14:09.000', 1535.3)
,('2021-11-08 00:15:09.000', 1535.5)
,('2021-11-08 00:16:09.000', 1536.0)
,('2021-11-08 00:17:09.000', 1528.6)
,('2021-11-08 00:28:09.000', 1542.5)
,('2021-11-08 00:29:09.000', 1543.3)

;with
    cte_partitions as
    (
        select *
        from
            (
                select   *
                    ,row_number() over(partition by M15.[partition] order by T.ts) as row_asc_id -- first row
                    ,row_number() over(partition by M15.[partition] order by T.ts desc) as row_desc_id -- last row
                from #t T
                    outer apply
                    (
                        -- 15 minutes partitions = hours + minutes / 15
                        select  format(ts, 'yyyyMMddHH') + cast(datepart(minute, ts) / 15 as char(1)) as [partition]
                    ) M15
            ) T
        where   T.row_asc_id = 1
            or  T.row_desc_id = 1
    )
select PF.ts
    ,PL.val - PF.val
from cte_partitions PF
    inner join cte_partitions PL
    on PF.[partition] = pl.[partition]
where PF.row_asc_id = 1
and PL.row_desc_id = 1
```

---

Although it's fully inline with your example, it will work only if you have every minute without seconds and so on and so forth.

take a look, please

```
create table #t
(
     ts datetime2
    ,val int
)

insert into #t
values
 ('2021-11-09T01:01:00.000Z', 100)
,('2021-11-09T01:02:00.000Z', 102)
,('2021-11-09T01:03:00.000Z', 103)
,('2021-11-09T01:04:00.000Z', 105)
,('2021-11-09T01:05:00.000Z', 107)
,('2021-11-09T01:06:00.000Z', 108)
,('2021-11-09T01:07:00.000Z', 120)
,('2021-11-09T01:08:00.000Z', 123)
,('2021-11-09T01:09:00.000Z', 128)
,('2021-11-09T01:10:00.000Z', 135)

select  format(ts, 'hh:mm:ss') + ' - ' + format(next_ts, 'hh:mm:ss')
        ,cast(next_val - val as varchar(10)) + ' (' + cast(next_val as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + cast(val as varchar(10)) + ')'
from
    (
        select   ts
                ,val
                ,lead(ts) over(order by ts) as next_ts
                ,lead(val) over(order by ts) as next_val
        from
            (
                select *, (row_number() over(order by ts) - 1) % 4 as row_id
                from #t
            ) SQ
        where row_id = 0
    ) SQ
where next_ts is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate them in windows of 5 minutes?
Then this may be as simple as also grouping by the minutes divided by 12.

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(t.[Timestamp]), 108), ' - ', CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(t.[Timestamp]), 108)) AS Agg_Timestamp,
 CONCAT(MAX(t.Energy_Value)-MIN(t.Energy_Value), ' (', MAX(t.Energy_Value), '-', MIN(t.Energy_Value), ')' ) AS Agg_Energy_Value
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY CAST(t.[Timestamp] AS DATE),
  DATEPART(hour, t.[Timestamp]),
  ROUND((DATEPART(minute, t.[Timestamp])/12.0), 0)
```

Result:

> ```
> Agg_Timestamp       | Agg_Energy_Value
> :------------------ | :---------------
> 01:01:00 - 01:05:00 | 7 (107-100)     
> 01:06:00 - 01:10:00 | 27 (135-108)
> ```